# Trying to setup environment for GeoNetwork metadata editor

Tags: eclipse, maven, metadata, geoserver, geonetwork

I'm trying to set up environment for Geonetwork metadata editor.  I've installed Java 1.5 SE with Tomcat 7.0. I've used [this tutorial](http://lab.usgin.org/groups/geonetwork-configuration-and-development/windows-7-64-bit-guide-geonetwork-development-within) to set it up. Everything went well up to part when should download dependencies and compile the code form package root folder from Eclipse with right click on the `pom.xml` file in the root folder and select `Run As | Maven package`. Then I get this error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building GeoNetwork opensource 2.9.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Caching xslt module 2.9.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:3.0.4 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] GeoNetwork opensource ............................. SUCCESS [0.001s]
[INFO] Caching xslt module ............................... FAILURE [0.027s]
[INFO] Jeeves modules .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Oaipmh modules .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ArcSDE module (dummy-api) ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] GeoNetwork web client module ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] GeoNetwork Web module ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] GeoServer module .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Gast module ....................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.476s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Aug 08 14:10:43 CEST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 3M/6M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.0.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:3.0.4: Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:3.0.4 in http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/github-releases was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of oss.sonatype.org-github-releases has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
```

I've googled but unsuccessful:(

Answer (score 0):

Use 1.6 JRE to run Geonetwork. It is written in the Geonetwork developers manual and also in the tutorial you linked.

Even so, you should be able to build with Java 1.5 also imho...

I had the same problems (JDK&JRE version 1.7.0_17) when building. I googled for the maven repositories and manually edited the url for the repository in the pom.xml file.

Because eclipse with maven likes likes to crash, I would suggest running maven from command line using the command mvn clean install. 
If you have to use maven in eclipse then I would suggest restarting eclipse and rerunning maven. 
Also, use the Geonetwork developers manual for building (google it, I cannot insert more that 2 links ;) ).

You also may find some clues in the [bug tracker](http://trac.osgeo.org/geonetwork/search) or in the [dev forum](http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/GeoNetwork-developer-f3874395.html) on why the build crashes.